# Internal linking between divs not working as expected

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a site with just one actual page containing multiple pseudo-pages in form of divs. There are four divs and I have set the width of the wrapper in which the divs are to 200%(so that I get two rows of two divs each) and set the divs to 50% width(so that they cover the whole page of the viewport).

I have four divs named home, like, dislike and contact. I first created a tag link to the like div and it worked. But tag links to no other divs are working and shows only the second page everytime.

Here is the jsfiddle : [JsFiddle of my site](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfzWg/)

What am I doing wrong?

Css:

```
#wrapper { max-width : 100%;
       overflow : hidden;
       position : relative; 
     }

#header { position : fixed;
    float : left;

    }

#logo { margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border : solid black;
background-color: red;
    }

#nav   {margin-top : 20px;
    width : 50%;
    height: 300px;  
    border : solid black;

}


#pages {  width: 200%;
      position : relative;
    border : solid black;
    float: left;
    height : 800px;
    }
#main-page, #like-page, #dislike-page, #contact-page {float:left;
position : relative;
width:50%;
height: 800px;}

div.content { margin-top: 100px;
}

div H2 {margin-left: 180px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;

}

div p {margin-left: 180px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle on what you are talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/X4URc/3/

I used html:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar'>
        <div align='center'> <a class='menu1 menu-item'>Item 1</a>
 <a class='menu2 menu-item'>Item 2</a>
 <a class='menu3 menu-item'>Item 3</a>
 <a class='menu4 menu-item'>Item 4</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <ul class='content-container'>
            <li class='contents content1'>Content 1</li>
            <li class='contents content2'>Content 2</li>
            <li class='contents content3'>Content 3</li>
            <li class='contents content4'>Content 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-item {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
.menu-item:not(.menu1) {
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.navbar {
    background: black;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 700px;
}
.container {
    background: white;
    width: 730px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content1 {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
.contents {
    padding-bottom: 400px;
    padding-right: 668px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
.contents:not(.content1) {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.content {
    width: 730px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content-container {
    width: 9999999px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.menu1').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-40px'});
});
$('.menu2').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-770px'});
});
$('.menu3').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-1500px'});
});
$('.menu4').click(function(){
    $('.content1').css({'margin-left' : '-2230px'});
});
// for more add -730px every time
//If you don't want animations change .animate() to .css()
```

Instead of having lots of divs, I used a `<ul>` within a div with overflow hidden and then styled it `display: inline;`

Comment: This is a great alternative way of doing it and I appreciate you coding it for me. But it doesnt answer what was wrong with my approach.

Comment: No need to apologise. Using jquery was not a problem, doing it with anchor tags was. Plus, with your approach, making it a fluid width layout would be a nightmare as I would have to use media query. But thanks nonetheless.